# Как изменить цвет курсора в консоли на С#

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить цвет курсора в консоли на С#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706552/how-to-change-the-cursor-color-c-sharp-console 
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/ConsoleCursorDisplay.aspx

Answer (score 1):

В C# вроде нет встроенной функции, которая устанавливает цвет курсора. Он устанавливается неявно, как дополнительный цвет к цвету фона (Console.BackgroundColor).
Попробуйте сделать вот так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Color
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ConsoleColor value = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.ForegroundColor = value;
            Console.CursorSize = 100; //Размер курсора 100-макс
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta; //
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```